# How to delete a database entry from ListBox?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm a bigginer need a help deleting from a Listbox. How can I make that when an item is selected in the Listbox and clicking on the delete button, how it delete this item in the sql database?

Here is where the data was reading from the database:

```
DataTable aucTable = new DataTable();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AuctionBase;Integrated Security=True");
SqlDataAdapter aucDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Auction", conn);

aucDa.Fill(aucTable);

listBox1.DataContext = aucTable;
```

The xaml code to see the data:

```
GridView ColumnHeaderToolTip="Auction"
 GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Product}" Header="Product" Width="150"
 GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=StartingPrice}"  Header="Starting Price" Width="120"
 GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CurrentPrice}"  Header="Current Price" Width="120"
</GridView>
```

The database:

```
CREATE TABLE Auction
(
    AuctionID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Product nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    StartingPrice int NOT NULL,
    CurrentPrice int NOT NULL 
);
```

And the delete button:

```
if(listBox1.SelectedIndex < 0)
{
    return;
}
else
{ 
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AuctionBase;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlDataAdapter aucDel = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand delete = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Auction WHERE AuctionID = @AuctionID", conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        delete.EndExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

What do I wrong and what is the solution? I want that when clicking the delete button the selected item in the ListBox should be deleted.

Comment: Is it only in the sample code that you have a `try` with no `catch` or `finally`? This won't compile.

Also the `if else` is not needed - just do if ` X >= 0` or just an `if` without the `else`

Comment: If you define a parameter placeholder in your query text  _AuctionID = @AuctionID_ then you need to add a parameter to the _delete_ command for that placeholder otherwise your code will trigger an exception

Comment: I get this error Message : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'asyncResult' of 'SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult)'

Comment: Use just ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: I used ExecuteNonQuery, and it still not want to delete the selected item from the database.

Comment: Do I need the SqlDataAdapter in the Delete Code?

Comment: No no SqlDataAdapter, but did you add the required parameter?